# Creating response doc from a selected document within a dataTable with XPages

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-domino

I try saving my document the document got saved without any error but the response document is no where to be found. The response document is a list of document in a datatable selected using a checkbox. The below code is placed on the  onchange event of the checkbox:

```
<xp:checkBox id="checkBox1" value="#{vProductListCollection}">
                                <xp:eventHandler   event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="norefresh"
                                    id="eventHandler1">
                                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var colTitle = vProductListCollection.getColumnValue("Title");
var prodTitle = viewScope.get("title");
var docId = viewScope.get("id");

var selDocID = vProductListCollection.getUniversalID();

if(docId.contains(selDocID )) {
prodTitle.remove(colTitle );
docId.remove(selDocID );
} else {
prodTitle.add(colTitle );
docId.add(selDocID );
}
}]]></xp:this.action>
                                </xp:eventHandler>
                            </xp:checkBox>
```

Postopen event:

```
var titleList = new java.util.ArrayList();
ViewScope.put('title', titleList );
var idList = new java.util.ArrayList();
viewScope.put('id', idList );
```

On my submit botton (to create response doc for NEW main document)  i have:

```
currentDocument.save()
var TL:java.util.ArrayList = viewScope.get("title");
var Id:java.util.ArrayList=viewScope.get("id");
for(var x=0;x<Id.size();x++){
 var doc=database.getDocumentByUNID(Id.get(x)); 
 var resdoc:NotesDocument=doc.copyToDatabase(database);
 resdoc.makeResponse(currentDocument.getDocument());
 resdoc.save();
}
```

When i submit my main document got saved but without the responce document, and hint?

Comment: You need to put the code into more context. The idList, title variables in your postopen are coming from where? Create a minimal XPages with the problem and provide the source

Comment: with the idList am just creating an Array, that will store the item from the selected document

Comment: TitleList goes nowhere. You added title to the scope not titlelist

Comment: @stwissel, do u have any idea why my response document is not been saved along with the main document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copyToDatabase()` doesn't work sometimes so well. The workaround and best practice is to create a new document and copy all items.

Your code could look like this then:

```
for(var x=0;x<Id.size();x++){
    var doc=database.getDocumentByUNID(Id.get(x)); 
    var resdoc:NotesDocument=database.createDocument();
    doc.copyAllItems(resdoc, false);
    resdoc.makeResponse(currentDocument.getDocument());
    resdoc.save();
}
```

*Update:*

I found the reason for not creating response documents: your Postopen(?) event code never gets executed as SSJS. It would throw an error as is has a capital letter "V" in "ViewScope.put('title'...". Because the code gets never executed viewScope "Id" remains empty and therefore the for-loop which would create response documents is never entered.

Put the correct code in **beforePageLoad** event and it will work.

```
<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    var titleList = new java.util.ArrayList();
    viewScope.put('title', titleList );
    var idList = new java.util.ArrayList();
    viewScope.put('id', idList );}]]>
</xp:this.beforePageLoad>
```

Comment: i tried that but my response doc did not save only the main document was saved

Comment: Are the response documents get created without being child of main document? You can find it out with a view sorted by "Last modified" and without option "Show response documents in a hierarchy".

Comment: the response document  was not created at all, i really dont know what am missing out

Comment: My guess is it doesn't loop through `for () { ... }`

Comment: if u go tru the code on my checkbox do u thing is correct or is i missing something out?

Comment: Please add a `print("Id.size: " + Id.size);` before `for ()` and look what it shows on server console.

Comment: Please add the *complete* code of checkbox to your question (not just the onchange code).

Comment: the print("Id.size: " + Id.size);return empty array, it has notting in it and the complete code of my checkbox is has be updated above

Comment: I tested your whole example and finally got it to work. I updated my answer. Hope it will work for you too :)

Comment: thanks you so much Knut, but if i may ask is it posible to make the checkedbox item remain check on edit mode of the document, that one would be able to add more item to the already sellected item and resaving them all togther?

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad you got it to work. Your question: isn't that how it works already?

Comment: yes its work, but buy try to make something like a order form, that if the submit and the nextday he can come and add or remove and resave  the previous selected response document without any save conflict

Comment: If I understand you right then you would have to look for "old" response documents with `currentDocument.getDocument().getResponses()`  *before* for-loop and remove the non-selected and add the new-selected *in* for-loop.

Comment: "remove the non-selected and add the new-selected in for-loop" i dont really get that becuase am new to XPages, how would i go about that and would the user be able to see what he has selected before probably he want to delete some of it.

Comment: Good point: yes you would have to check checkbox by default if document is already a response document. You would create a javascript for "defaultChecked" parameter in checkbox which returns "true" if it is a response document already.

Comment: thanks for your ideas i tried the below code be i got no valid respond for(var x=0;x<resId.size();x++){
 var doc=database.getDocumentByUNID(resId.get(x));
 if(id.contains(resId )) {
 return true
} else {
 return false
 }
}

Comment: You have to add code to checkBox `<xp:checkBox id="checkBox1" defaultChecked="#{javascript:...return true if document is already a response document...}"`. But to be honest: it is kind of impossible to develop and deliver you the solution in comments.