# Making a checkbox return true if document is already a response

Tags: javascript, xpages

I would like my checkbox to return true if document is already response document.
i have tried below code but was not working any suggestion?

```
var Id:java.util.ArrayList=viewScope.get("idList")
var resId:java.util.ArrayList=currentDocument.getDocument().getResponses();  
for (var x=0;x<resId.size();x++){
    var doc=database.getDocumentByUNID(resId.get(x));   
    if(id.contains(resId )) { 
        return true; 
    } else {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

This question is the follow up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23778740/2065611).

Comment: Do you want the checkbox to be checked if it's a response document? Or do you want an onclick event of the checkbox to run a function that, if it's a response document, it returns true?

Bear in mind a checkbox doesn't return anything, it's bound to something and passes one value if it's checked and another if it's not. If you want to change the return value, you probably want to look at checkedValue, uncheckedValue and defaultChecked properties :-)

Comment: @Paul, A response document was created and save, with a datatable,so i want if the the main document was Open in edit mode 
the checkbox should return or check the already saved response document by default

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the checkbox should return". Properties can return true or false, but a checkbox can only return a value back to whatever document item or scoped variable it's bound to.

Answer (score 0):

Knut talks about setting the defaultChecked value. That's just going to be the default when the page is opened. If you're looking to check a checkbox programmatically, use getComponent("myCheckbox").setChecked(true).

Remember all properties in the All Properties area have getters and setters (for booleans the setter will be e.g. isChecked())

Comment: What I understood so far: Simon has a form (= main document) with a list of potential response documents in a data table. After submit he makes copies of selected documents and makes them responses to form document. If user opens this form next time the response documents shall be selected in data table.

Comment: You're right, it needs to be the calculation to return whether defaultChecked should be true / false, so on that property. If it's not working, the key is debugging why it's not working, with print statements or SSJS debugger. One warning light on a brief review is currentDocument goes to the nearest instance of dominoDocument, so may or may not be the main document. Generic debugging techniques (see the chapter in Mastering XPages) will help track it down.